# Karate / Gatling : Error : java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [2 seconds]

Tags: karate

We are using Karate for our Services test in our CI and it is going on well for a long time, now trying to see if we could use Karate/Gatling integration to run perf tests using our feature files.
Karate version used : 0.8.0.1

Here is the mvn command

> mvn clean test-compile gatling:test -Denv.users=1 -Denv.ramptime=1
>   -Denv.duration=1 -Denv.feature=axxx.feature -Dkarate.env=xxxx

Here is the snippet from scala script

> val featureTest =
>   scenario("test").forever(){exec(karateFeature("classpath:xx/xxx.feature))}
>   setUp(
>       featureTest.inject(rampUsers(userno.toInt) over (ramptime.toInt seconds))).maxDuration(duration.toInt minutes)    after {
>       println("Simulation is Complete!")

Here is the error I get

> Simulation xxx.testcases.profilesSimulation completed in 60 seconds
>   Simulation is Complete! java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.runMain(MainWithArgsInFile.java:50)
>           at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:33)
>   Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out
>   after [2 seconds]
>           at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:255)
>           at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:259)
>           at scala.concurrent.Await$.$anonfun$result$1(package.scala:215)
>           at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
>           at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:142)
>           at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:66)
>           at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromArgs(Gatling.scala:45)
>           at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.main(Gatling.scala:37)
>           at io.gatling.app.Gatling.main(Gatling.scala)

==
Anyone knows what is going on here and how to resolve

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to 0.9.1

Also it would help us if you try the develop branch as well: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide

And help us simulate the problem if there is an issue: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thanks, 0.9.1 didn't help. Will try to simulate the problem with a simpler scenario and submit.